# HttpErrorResponse in my angular + nodejs web page

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, mongodb

I have been trying to create a server and integrate it with a front-end. I created a server using NodeJS. Created a few API requests and responses that create patients through a signup form. When I try to integrate it with an angular front-end, I keep getting the same error, 404 page not found with the url that I had given as Base url in my front-end service.

this is my route from the server side,

server.js (the main file in the server)

```
import express,{json,urlencoded} from 'express';
import cors from "cors";
import db from './App/Models/index.js';
import {patientrouter} from './App/Routes/patient.routes.js'
import { caretakerrouter } from "./App/Routes/caretaker.routes.js";
import { doctorrouter } from './App/Routes/doctor.routes.js';

const app = express()
var corurl = {origin: "http://localhost:8080"}

app.use(cors(corurl))
app.use(json())
app.use(urlencoded({extended: true }))

/* REQUESTS and ROUTES */

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({Message:"Hello, Welcome to Wearable."})
})

app.use('/add', patientrouter);
// app.use('/Doctor', doctorrouter);
// app.use('/CareTaker', caretakerrouter);

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}.`);
});
```

patient.route.js (the routes handling file.)

```
import {Patientcreate, PatientFindAll, PatientFindOne, PatientUpdate} from '../Controllers/patient.controller.js'
import {Router as routerman} from 'express'

const patientrouter = routerman()
patientrouter.post("/",Patientcreate)
patientrouter.get("/",PatientFindAll)
patientrouter.get("/Find/:Name",PatientFindOne)
patientrouter.put("/Update/:ID",PatientUpdate)



export {patientrouter}
```

on the front-end this is my routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddPatientComponent } from "./components/add-patient/add-patient.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'patient', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'add', component: AddPatientComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

patient.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Patient } from "../models/patient.model";

const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/add'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PatientService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  create(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(baseUrl, data);
  }
}
```

addpatient.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Patient } from "src/app/models/patient.model";
import { PatientService } from "src/app/service/patient.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-patient',
  templateUrl: './add-patient.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-patient.component.css']
})
export class AddPatientComponent implements OnInit{

  patient: Patient = {
    Name: '',
    Mobile_Number: NaN,
    Username: '',
    Password: '',
    Gender: ''
  };
  submitted = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.submitted)
  }
  constructor(private patientservice: PatientService){}

  savepatient(): void {
    const data = {
      Name: this.patient.Name,
      Username: this.patient.Username,
      Password:this.patient.Password,
      Mobile_Number:this.patient.Mobile_Number,
      Gender:this.patient.Gender

    };

    console.log(data)

    this.patientservice.create(data)
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e)
      });
  }

  newpatient(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.patient = {
      Name: '',
      Username: '',
      Password: '',
      Mobile_Number: NaN,
      Gender: ''
    };
  }

}
```

I have tried to check my server with postman and that seems to work fine. But once it goes onto the web with angular, the error is back. I am unsure of what exactly is supposed to happen actually. I assumed that the service would be called and the function would be run and data will be added through my server. Do let me know about how to integrate frontend and backend, am I missing something important? what is the error here? The code is based on the code from the bezkoder website and my nodejs angular and mongodb are all in the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen your console yet? It looks like a *cors problem* (even though you have it "enabled"). Anyway, what is the error shown on your console?

Comment: I changed my code a bit and ended with this `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/users' from origin 'http://localhost:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy:` so you are right. But How do i solve this issue?

Comment: ok, i think that makes it a little easier. Replace the `app.use(cors(corurl)) ` and add `app.use(cors())` instead. Remember this will allow your API to receive requests from all origins. Make this change just for a simple test

Comment: I solved it. When I didn't remove the corurl, but instead managed to match my origin and request initiator urls and then i got a 400 bad request error. I found out that it was happening because of a typo.